# Error while using repository pattern

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am using repository pattern and getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'Pricehunter.DataLayer.Data.Category' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'IRepository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Pricehunter.DataLayer.Data.Category' to 'Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.IObjectState'.   Pricehunter.DataLayer   E:\Development\PriceHunter\Pricehunter.DataLayer\Interfaces\ICategoryRepository.cs  12  Active

while implement this line of code.I viewed some question but can not get the point to resolve it.

```
public interface ICategoryRepository : IRepository<Category>
{
    Category GetCategory();
}
```

Comment: What about the error do you not understand? It clearly states that `Category` can't be used as the type parameter because it cannot be converted to `IObjectState`...

Comment: so how I can resolve it

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something but the obvious answer is to make Category implement the `IObjectState` interface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IObjectState is available only if the entity classes or POCO classes are inherited from ENTITY class. This way you can Modify the state.

```
public partial class myPocoClass : Entity
{
}
public abstract class Entity : IObjectState
{
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```